# How to back up OS and application preferences on Mac OS X Lion for reinstalling?

Tags: macos, backup, osx-lion, reinstall, system-preferences

The title pretty much says it all. I'm happy to copy folders, or use a utility. I know a lot of preferences are kept in ~/user/Library/Application Support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup your system using Time Machine.

Then you can erase the entire disk, install Lion cleanly, and just restore e.g. user accounts, but not applications.

Comment: Interesting. I'll definitely try this next time.